# Only show size attributes in product box woocommerce when available

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

First of all I want to say I have little coding experience. I want to show available sizes in the productbox on the shop page. I got this working after some searching around here. Now I want to only display the sizes when sizes are available. If there are no size attributes available I would like the text: No sizes available or no text at all.

[image: Example]

I got the following code now:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5);


function display_size_attribute() {

    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('external')) {

        $taxonomy = 'pa_maat';

        echo "Maten:";
        echo '<span class="attribute-size">' 
                . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) 
        . '</span>';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

to test is the text is not empty, try that :

```
function display_size_attribute() {

    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('external')) {

        $taxonomy = 'pa_maat';

        $text = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

        if (!empty($text)) {
            echo "Maten:";
            echo '<span class="attribute-size">' 
                    . htmlspecialchars($text) 
            . '</span>';
        }

    } // END if ($product->is_type('external')) {


} // END function display_size_attribute() {
```

Comment: Doesnt work :( Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_empty() in wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:27

Comment: oh yes, I edited the code, try it now.

Comment: It works! Thanks you are a lifesaver!